# How to use sed in shell script to replace all environment value occurrences with their current values

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I would like to have a shell script to iterate over all the occurrences of environment variable names in a file and replace them with their current values. I am not sure how this can be done by using `sed` command.

The file content:

```
values:
  value1: 
    name: "something"
    value: "$ENV_VAR1" # this could be any variable name
  value2: 
    name: "something"
    value: "$ENV_VAR2" 
...
```

First, I need to find all occurrences of any variable (Using regex `"\$(.*?)"` ). Then, somehow, I need to replace it with the variable value from the shell. I am not sure how I can use the `sed` command to achieve the second part as the variable name is specified in the file itself.

Something like the following command:

```
sed -i "s/\"\$(.*?)\"/${Some_How_Get_Var_Name}/g" file.yaml
```

Comment: Is this an YAML file? suggest using a proper language aware parser like `yq`

Comment: `perl -pe 'while (my ($k, $v) = each %ENV) { s/\$$k/$v/g }'`

Comment: @Inian yes it is a yaml file. I am running this on a basic alpine image that has a very limited bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem that comes up often.  `envsubst` is commonly given as a solution, but I find it's easier to just stick with `perl` and do something like:

```
perl -pe 'while (my ($k, $v) = each %ENV) { s/\$$k/$v/g }'
```

This is almost certainly not a robust solution (it will replace `$FOO`, but it won't do replacements of the form `${FOO}`), but I find I'm always disappointed that `envsubst` doesn't do `${FOO-bar}`, and `envsubst` seems less ubiquitous than `perl`.

Or, rather than doing the replacement for everything in the environment, you might prefer something like:

```
perl -pe 's/\$([[:alpha:]_][_[:alnum:]]+)/$ENV{$1}/g'
```

or

```
perl -pe 's/\$([[:alpha:]_][\w]+)/$ENV{$1}/g'
```

These last two will replace '$FOO' with the empty string if FOO is not defined, while the first leaves it unreplaced.  Which behavior you desire may drive the decision as to which to use.

I won't claim these are completely correct, but they are a reasonable approximation.

Answer (score 2):

If You are using `bash` and the `envsubst` command is avaiable you can do:

```
 envsubst < inputfile
```

E.g. (creating a temp input for demonstrating it:

```
$ env | tail -2 | sed 's_^_$_'
$MANPATH=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/man:
$INFOPATH=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/info:
```

Then running this through `envsubst`:

```
$ env | tail -2 | sed 's_^_$_' | envsubst
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/man:=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/man:
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/info:=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/info:
```

Comment: It appears that envsubst is not available in the alpine distro

Comment: Actually it is: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?branch=edge&name=gettext&arch=x86_64&repo=main You just need to install gettext

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/value:/{y/"/\n/;s/^.*/printf "&"/e;y/\n/"/}' file
```

On any line containing the string `value:` convert any `"`'s to newlines, use printf to convert the environmental variables to their real values and reconvert the introduced newlines back to `"`'s.

N.B. If the environmental variable can contain `"`'s, these will need to be quoted following the printf command, i.e. insert `s/"/\\"/g` before the last `y` command.